# Problems to reduce from to prove an $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds

What are the standard problems we can reduce from to prove $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bounds?

Of course, state problems other than sorting and element distinctness.

Comment: In what computational model?

Comment: Good point. I meant the comparision based model.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Ben-Or](http://www.cse.huji.ac.il/~benor/AlgCompTrees83.pdf) directly proved  $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bounds for several fundamental problems in the algebraic computation tree model:

- Element distinctness: Given an array of $n$ real numbers, are its elements distinct?
- Set disjointness: Given two sets of $n$ real numbers, do they have an element in common?
- Set equality: Given two sets of $n$ real numbers, is one array a permutation of the other?
- Measure problem: Given $n$ real intervals, what is the total length of their union?
- Set inclusion: Given two sets of real numbers, is one a subset of the other?
- Permutation Parity: Given an permutation of the set $[n]$, is the permutation even or odd?

The first three are the ones most often used in computational geometry.

Comment: irrelevant aside: the first three are also the canonical hard problems for communication-complexity-based stream algorithm lower bounds.

Comment: @SureshVenkat - I have seen set disjointness and set equality being used for proving lower bounds in streaming. Do you have an example for element distinctness?

Comment: At least one place I saw it was in the analysis of algorithms under the W-stream model. In general, ED is closely related to bit-vector (or set) disjointness